# Phaser 3 Multiple Pointer Events in one

Tags: pointers, phaser-framework, pointer-events

I currently have two pointer events which essentially do the same thing:

```
gameState.idle.on('pointerout', function(){
    scene.sys.canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
    gameState.pet_cursor.alpha = 0;
});
gameState.idle.on('pointerup', function(){
    scene.sys.canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
    gameState.pet_cursor.alpha = 0;
});
```

Is there any way to combine these two? For example, I tried `gameState.idle.on('pointerup, pointerout', function(){});`, but that evidently didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, **but** you could just write one *handler function* and use it for both/multiple events.

***like this:***

```
...
function mouseHandler(){
    scene.sys.canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
    gameState.pet_cursor.alpha = 0;
}

function create() {
    ...
    gameState.idle.on('pointerout', mouseHandler);
    gameState.idle.on('pointerup', mouseHandler);
    ...
}
```

> **Important:** not parentheses after `mouseHandler`, in the event handler.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was debating on doing something like that if there were no other options, looks like that's what I'll do. Too bad, but that's good to know! Thank you again :)